# No Write Access to WD My Cloud NAS on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: file-permissions, network-attached-storage

I recently purchased a new WD My Cloud and was able to use the FTP app to transfer files from an old machine that was running OMV to the new NAS. I cannot seem to mount the NAS to my Ubuntu laptop properly to enable write access, however. I've included the output of my `/etc/fstab` file (I have also mounted the NAS with the username and password of the admin user as opposed to `guest`), as well as various information related to file permissions and the things that aren't working that I would expect to work (the copy operations). Ideally I don't want to have to assume root privilege to write to the NAS, but I'll take that for now as a stopgap.

```
~: cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=28376594-b7ab-42c1-bb8c-71a3c5a799e1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=E00C-C026  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
//192.168.1.221/Public /media/big-turtle cifs rw,user,guest,vers=3.0

~: sudo umount /media/big-turtle
umount: /media/big-turtle: not mounted.

~: mount /media/big-turtle
mount: (hint) your fstab has been modified, but systemd still uses
       the old version; use 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload.

~: cd /media/big-turtle
big-turtle: ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 dan  dan     0 Jul  4 13:16  ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jul  4 13:51  ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 dan  dan     0 Jul  4 13:25  Movies/
drwxr-xr-x 2 dan  dan     0 Jul  4 12:22 'Screen Art'/
drwxr-xr-x 2 dan  dan     0 Jul  4 10:26  Television/

big-turtle: whoami
dan

big-turtle: ll -n
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000    0 Jul  4 13:16  ./
drwxr-xr-x 6    0    0 4096 Jul  4 13:51  ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000    0 Jul  4 13:25  Movies/
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000    0 Jul  4 12:22 'Screen Art'/
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000    0 Jul  4 10:26  Television/

big-turtle: id
uid=1000(dan) gid=1000(dan) groups=1000(dan),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),121(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare)

big-turtle: mv ~/Downloads/Go.1999.720p.BluRay.999MB.HQ.x265.10bit-GalaxyRG\[TGx]/Go.mkv /media/big-turtle/Movies
mv: cannot create regular file '/media/big-turtle/Movies/Go.mkv': Permission denied

big-turtle: sudo mv ~/Downloads/Go.1999.720p.BluRay.999MB.HQ.x265.10bit-GalaxyRG\[TGx]/Go.mkv /media/big-turtle/Movies
[sudo] password for dan: 
mv: cannot create regular file '/media/big-turtle/Movies/Go.mkv': Permission denied

big-turtle: lsattr /media/big-turtle
lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on /media/big-turtle/Television
lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on /media/big-turtle/Movies
lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on /media/big-turtle/Screen Art
```

Comment: What is output of: `id`, and `whoami` and `ll -n` ?  What happens when you do `sudo -su dan` >

Comment: I've updated my console output to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to SSH into the NAS itself and change the file permissions there - the owner of the file was root and I needed to change it to the admin user. Now, when I include the admin username and password in the `/etc/fstab` file, I am able to write to the NAS.